# bash to get information from two files

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have file1:

```
NM_000014   A2M
NM_000015   NAT2
NM_000016   ACADM
NM_000017   ACADS
NM_000018   ACADVL
NM_000019   ACAT1
NM_000020   ACVRL1
NM_000021   PSEN1
NM_000022   ADA
```

And file2:

```
NM_000019   
NM_000020   
NM_000020
NM_12345
```

I need to get information from my file1 and put it to file2 - so create file3:

```
NM_000019   ACAT1
NM_000020   ACVRL1
NM_000020   ACVRL1
NM_12345    NO
```

Note - I can not change a original sort order (so not use comm and diff). I have duplication line in file2 - this I need keep (wc -l file2 == wc -l file3). If there is no match - print `NO`

I have about 70K rows and I do not need fastest solution. 
My code is able just compare and print the same results.

code:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r c; do


grep $c file1  | uniq 

done < file2 > file3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print ($1 in a?$1 OFS a[$1]:$1 OFS "NO")}' file1 file2
NM_000019 ACAT1
NM_000020 ACVRL1
NM_000020 ACVRL1
NM_12345 NO
```

Explained:

```
NR==FNR{                                      # process the first file
    a[$1]=$2                                  # hash records to a, $1 as key
    next                                      # skip to next record
} 
{                                             # process the second file
    print ($1 in a?$1 OFS a[$1]:$1 OFS "NO")  # print hashed value if found or NO

#   if($1 in a)                               # another way of saying above
#       print $1, a[$1] 
#   else 
#       print $1, "NO"
}
```

Comment: For completeness, you could add `awk -v OFS="\t" '#my awk code ....' file1 file2` to make fields separated by tabs

Comment: @Aserre Thanks, didn't see tabs mentioned so I skipped that.

Comment: @JamesBrown Thank you for perfect awk solution.. very interested is, that in your solution is condition applies wc -l file2 == wc -l file3!!

Comment: @Geroge Yes. For each record in file2 the script outputs another record.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you have one file with patterns, and a second one that you want to search using those patterns:

```
#!/bin/bash

for PATTERN in $(cat $2); do
    TMP=$(egrep $PATTERN $1)
    if [ ! -z "$TMP" ]; then
        echo "$TMP" 
    else
        echo "$PATTERN NO"
    fi
done
```

and a quick test:

```
$ bash filter.sh file1 file2
NM_000019   ACAT1
NM_000020   ACVRL1
NM_000020   ACVRL1
NM_12345 NO
```

Comment: This is very nice to you bash and input files directly from terminal. could you please explain me what is the part for reading files direct form terminal? This: $(cat $2) ??

Comment: Well, it's really simplistic, the nth commandline parameter can be referenced using $n ... that's it :-) So the assumption is, that the file with the data is passed. See in example: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams or directly in the bash manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Positional-Parameters

Answer (score 1):

Try with this `if` sentence added to your code:

```
if ! grep -q $i fileone ; then
  echo -e $i "   NO"
fi
```

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r c; do grep $c fileone  | uniq; done < filetwo
for i in $(cat filetwo)
do
  if ! grep -q $i fileone ; then
    echo -e $i "   NO"
  fi
done
```

It will print NO in case of no matches of a line of file2 in file1.

Answer (score 0):

Try paste command. This is less noble form than awk. I prefer awk but paste command should help you.

paste file1 file2 file3... etc ..fileN

You can redirect command output to a file as usual.

paste file1 file2 file3... etc ..fileN > fileN+1 (or whatever)

Thats read files line by line and paralelize output sequentially way.

That's it. It is not very elegant but sometimes it is very useful until you find a different way to get the results you are looking for.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for sharing.. I think that paste could works only when my data are sorted isnt it? Problem is, that I need to keep input sort order..

Comment: Paste command don't change the order of the data as data are in file, print them line by line concatenating the different files. That is, first row file1, first row file2..... If your data are previously sorted, paste command don't alter that.